# Placing text over absolute image

Tags: html, css

A similar question has been asked many times (how to place text over an image) but every solution says make a relative positioned container and place image and text inside.

**But what if the container needs to be absolute??**

I want the image to be absolute in order to span the full width of the page, without being limited by the wrapper's width: Wrapper has set width, the image container should ignore this and be full screen, and the text should float above the image.

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2tpbx12x/) in which the image isn't ignoring the wrapper's width

```css
.splash_image {
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
  top: 2%;
  height: 600px;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
}
.splash_image img {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}
.splash_title {
  color: red;
  position: absolute;
}
.wrapper {
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="splash_image">
    <img src="http://fc07.deviantart.net/fs34/f/2008/290/6/4/Large_Tree_Stock_by_HauntingVisionsStock.jpg" alt="test image">
    <div class="splash_title">Test title to go here on image</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So remove `position: relative` from `.splash_image`

Comment: What would be the default positioning of .splash_image? When I remove relative, it no longer has an affect on the image overflow.

For instance, if you change the .splash_image height to 60px instead of 600 and remove position relative from .splash_image, it does not crop 

https://jsfiddle.net/2tpbx12x/3/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You set relative positioning on the image container, so even though you've positioned the image absolutely, it's being positioned absolutely within a relative positioned container. The container should be positioned absolutely if I am understanding what you're looking for:

```
.splash_image{
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:2%;
    height:600px;
    width:100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 1;
  }
  .splash_image img{
    width:100%;
  }
.splash_title{
  color:red;
  z-index: 88;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
}
```

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2tpbx12x/2/)

Comment: Thank you! I incorrectly thought the img needed a defined position, so this method never made it in my series of combinations.

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple ways to accomplish this. Here is a simple answer:

```css
.splash_image {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 2%;
  height: 600px;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
}
.splash_image img {
  width: 100%;
}
.splash_title {
  color: red;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
}
.wrapper {
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
 <div class="splash_image">
     <img src="http://fc07.deviantart.net/fs34/f/2008/290/6/4/Large_Tree_Stock_by_HauntingVisionsStock.jpg" alt="test image" />
  </div>
<div class="wrapper">
     <div class="splash_title">Test title to go here on image</div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jonnysynthetic/2vqgab7t/

However, you could also try setting the image as a background to the parent element as well. I wasn't sure of the scope of what this is in or a part of, so I wanted to give you the simple answer first.

Answer (score 1):

```
.splash_image{
  left: 0;
  top: 2%;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  height: 100%;
}
.splash_image img{
  width:100%;
  position:absolute;
}
.splash_title{
  color: red;
  z-index: 88;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50px;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
.wrapper{
  width: 50%;
  height: 150px;
  position: relative;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2tpbx12x/5/

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 .splash_image img{
    width:100%;
    position:fixed;
  }
```